# Proving a continuous function on a closed interval that never repeats a value is strictly increasing

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

Suppose a function $f(x)$ is continuous on a closed interval $I = [a, b]$, and that $f(I) = [f(a), f(b)]$. Suppose further that as $x$ varies over $I$, $f(x)$ never repeats a value. Prove $f(x)$ is strictly increasing.

Intuitively, I can see that if $f(x)$ were not strictly increasing, it would have to repeat at one point $k \in [a,b]$ so that $f(k)$ = $f(n)$ for some $n \in [a,k)$.

How could I go about proving this formally? I suspect that it has to do with the intermediate value property of continuous functions on a closed interval, since the reverse argument holds (if $f(x)$ is strictly increasing on $[a,b]$ and has the IVP, then it is continuous on $[a,b]$.)

Thank you!

Comment: The right conclusion should be *strictly monotonic*. The function could just be decreasing. If it is not strictly monotonic, then there are points $x_1\leq x_2\leq x_3$ such that either $f(x_1)\leq f(x_2)\geq f(x_3)$ or $f(x_1)\geq f(x_2)\leq f(x_3)$. If you had the first case, then the value $\max(f(x_1),f(x_3))$ is between $f(x_1)$ and $f(x_2)$ and in between $f(x_2)$ and $f(x_3)$. Therefore, by the IVT it is attained in both $[x_1,x_2]$ and in $[x_2,x_3]$. For the other case it is the same idea, but look at $\min(f(x_1),f(x_3))$.

Comment: Have you tried proving the contrapositive?  I haven't written it out, but it looks easy.

Comment: @yixing $f(I) = [f(a), f(b)]$

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 If that presupposes that $f(b)\geq f(a)$, then maybe.

Comment: @yixing It's implicit. The notation for the closed interval $[a,b]$ typically presumes $a \leq b$.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 Typically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $f(x)$ is not strictly increasing.

That is, there exists $x<y$ s.t. $f(x)\geq f(y)$.

$f(a) \leq f(y)$. Therefore $f(a) \leq f(y) \leq f(x)$.

By IVT, there exists $c\in [a,x]$ s.t. $f(c) = f(y)$.